# Migrating CKAN on Ubuntu 14 to Redhat Linux 7

Tags: ubuntu, migration, redhat, ckan

what is the proper way to migrate CKAN application and data currently on Ubuntu 14.04 to Red Hat Linux 7. Can you please point me to documentation as well? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this down into two parts:

1. Running CKAN on RHEL 7

   For distributions other than Ubuntu, the CKAN community shares guides on its wiki. e.g. You may have success with: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.7.2-on-CentOS-7.4
2. Migrating CKAN data & config from one server to another

   - For Postgres you would [dump and restore](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/database-management.html#dumping-and-loading-databases-to-from-a-file)
   - Copy config files. The key one is: /etc/ckan/default/production.ini

Comment: Hello @D Read, thank you for your response. I will carefully read thru the doc pages. We are at the UofCalgary using mysql as database so can you please point me to the right documentation.

Comment: Mysql is not supported. If you can't install postgres directly then try using it via Docker or AWS RDS or something.

Comment: Yes, we can have postgresql. Thanks D Read!

Comment: Hi David, you pointed me to version 2.7.2, is there reason why I should not getting version 2.8? Currently our production instance is 2.7.2 http://yycdatacollective.ucalgary.ca/

Comment: I answered about 2.7 because you asked about 2.7 :) The CKAN tech team focus on the official path of using Ubuntu. I don't have any advice about compatibility with other distros. You could try asking in a fresh question.

Comment: Hi, how did you know that I used CKAN 2.7, I read again but did not see anywhere I mentioned version 2.7? This may be useful for me to know how you figured it out? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't, but install instructions don't change much between releases